# How to get all the values from multiple keys of an array of object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I need to get values from multiple keys from an array of object.

```
trip = [
    {sp: 'cbe', ep: 'tpr'}, 
    {sp: 'tpr', ep: 'erd'}, 
    {sp: 'erd', ep: 'blr'}
];
```

The output should be `["cbe", "tpr", "erd", "blr"]`

what I tried is posted as an answer and it works but I used two maps to get the desired output. I know there should be a way better than my answer.

Here is my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1ar6y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) on stackblitz

Answer (score 3):

The new [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) function can be used here, but be aware of limited browser support

```js
trip = [
    {sp: 'cbe', ep: 'tpr'}, 
    {sp: 'tpr', ep: 'erd'}, 
    {sp: 'erd', ep: 'blr'}
];

res = [ ...new Set(   trip.flatMap(Object.values)    )]

console.log(res)
```

Comment: can you tell ,me what flatmap does?

Comment: @anonymous Just follow the link in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const trip = [
        {sp: 'cbe', ep: 'tpr'}, 
        {sp: 'tpr', ep: 'erd'}, 
        {sp: 'erd', ep: 'blr'}
    ];
    const r = trip.map( m => {
      return m.sp
    });
    const s = trip.map( m => {
      return m.ep
    });
    console.log(Array.from(new Set(r.concat(s))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way: (updated to aggregate all keys instead of explicit keys)

```js
const trip = [
    {sp: 'cbe', ep: 'tpr'}, 
    {sp: 'tpr', ep: 'erd'}, 
    {sp: 'erd', ep: 'blr'}
];

const t = Array.from(trip.reduce((a, el) => {
    for (let key in el) a.add(el[key]);
    return a;
}, new Set()));

console.log(t);
```

Comment: I don't think you explicitly need to provide an empty array to the `Set` constructor. Also, the final result here will be a `Set` not an array. You can fix that with `Array.from(trip.reduce...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are O.K. with not-so-much readable one-liner…

```js
trip = [{
    sp: 'cbe',
    ep: 'tpr'
  },
  {
    sp: 'tpr',
    ep: 'erd'
  },
  {
    sp: 'erd',
    ep: 'blr'
  }
];

const res = [...new Set([].concat.apply([], trip.map(item => Object.values(item))))];

console.log(res);
```